# How do I run code BEFORE my package namespace is loaded?

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I am messing around with some R internals, and I'm trying to see if I can change the functions which are exported based on the current state of the user's R session (i.e., change the name of a function based on whether a package is loaded or not). I realize that this is a terrible idea in practice! Anyway, to do this, I will need to run code before the namespace is loaded. The `.onLoad` function is run AFTER the namespace is loaded; is there a way to set a hook to run code BEFORE the namespace is loaded? Here is information I found in `userhooks{base}`, which lists namespace loading as the first thing that happens.

> The sequence of events depends on which hooks are defined, and whether a package is attached or just loaded. In the case where all hooks are defined and a package is attached, the order of initialization events is as follows:
>
> 1. The package namespace is loaded.
> 2. The package's .onLoad function is run.
> 3. The namespace is sealed.
> 4. The user's "onLoad" hook is run.
> 5. The package is added to the search path.
> 6. The package's .onAttach function is run.
> 7. The package environment is sealed.
> 8. The user's "attach" hook is run.

Comment: maybe you can first export no function, then look at the user's namespace, then make a direct access to the one you want with something like `fun = mypakckage:::fun` ?

Comment: I can make direct access to the functions I want in `.onLoad()`, but then I want to export the functions I dynamically created. So then I guess I would have to call `loadNamespace()` within my `.onLoad()`... but if `loadNamespace()` triggers `onLoad()`, it seems like that could cause bad recursive effects.